# Is there any summary of cavity QED and spin resonance related effects and splittings?

Tags: atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, nuclear-magnetic-resonance, cavity-qed, rabi-model

I recently started working on NMR-based qubits and I have lots of confusion regarding the definitions of different interactions and energy level splitting phenomenon. I wonder if you know any reference that comprehensively summarizes these phenomena such as Stark, Zeeman effects, Autler-Townes splitting, Larmor and Rabi frequency (especially different forms of Rabi frequency under magnetic field, due to hyperfine splitting, in free-space and in cavity etc.)

Comment: Except for Autler-Townes splitting, these topics are covered in most standard quantum optics textbooks. I thank that a specification of what excatly you are looking for might help.

Comment: Instead of individual treatment, I was looking for a summary on an actual system.